# Output to a file from a remote PC using command line

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems, batch-file

I using PC1 and PC2. PC1 is running the command and PC2 is the remote PC.

I am performing the following operation and I am trying to output it to a file but on PC1.

```
runas /user:[username] "psexec -e -h -s -u [username] -p [password] \\[IP] cmd /C ipconfig /displaydns > c:\[remotePC.txt]"
```

I need c:[remotePC.txt] to be output on the caller PC1. 
What is the correct syntax for this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
    runas /user:[username] "psexec -e -h -s -u [username] -p [password] \\[IP] cmd /C ipconfig /displaydns > \\[PC1 IP]\C$\log.txt"
```

Comment: So for the `-u [username] -p [password]` portion, can you confirm that this account/security context has applicable access to the `\\[PC1 IP]\C$` admin share to write to it on `PC1`? Can you sign onto the machine you're running this process on but sign onto it with the `-u [username] -p [password]` you are running this process as otherwise and confirm that you can get to `\\[PC1 IP]\C$`, create a new file and write to it there? This should be a simple and easy way to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Output file should point to `\\computer name\c$\filename.txt`

Comment: I tried that but no file is created and no error is displayed. Thanks

Comment: Huh, say what, come again???

Comment: As @Walmart mentioned, are you able to sign into the machine with the credentials you are providing?